# Data binding not working when using a custom view

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, binding, maui

Im developing application using .NET MAUI framework, as part of my app there is a PostView which suppose to present some data.
When im trying to bind instance of Post the binding isn't working and the app just display an empty template of PostView.

This is my Post model

```
public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part of the page that renders the PostView

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Post">
            <views:PostView
            Post="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is PostView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PostView
{

    public PostView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PostProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Post),
            typeof(Post), 
            typeof(PostView), 
            default(Post));

    public Post Post
    {
        get { return (Post)GetValue(PostProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PostProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

this is part of PostView.xaml

```
  <Grid        
         x:Name="self"
         MaximumHeightRequest="500"
         RowDefinitions="Auto,*,266,Auto"
         ColumnDefinitions="*"
         RowSpacing="6"
         HorizontalOptions="Start"
         >
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*" ColumnSpacing="12">
        <Frame Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" CornerRadius="20"  IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Image Source="{Binding Post.Business.ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="-20"/>
        </Frame>
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Text="{Binding Post.Business.Name}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Post.CreatedAt}"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Post.Caption}"/>
    <Frame Grid.Row="2" IsClippedToBounds="True">
        <Image Source="{Binding Post.ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="360" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="-20"/>
    </Frame>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Like"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to set the BindingContext of PostView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be removing `Posts` from `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">` and assign the list to the object using code

```
collectionName.Source = yourList
```

Answer (score 0):

Data binding doesn't seem to be done correctly.
Change `<views:PostView Post="{Binding}"/>` in the CollectionView.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Post">
            <views:PostView Post="{Binding}"/> <!-- change this line -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Try

```
<views:PostView Post="{Binding .}"/>
```

The "." is reference to an item in `Posts` bound to the `CollectionView`.